# What are "Android SDK Tools", "Android SDK Platform Tools" and "Android SDK Build tools"?

Tags: android, android-build, android-sdk-tools

What are "Android SDK Tools", "Android SDK Platform Tools" and "Android SDK Build tools"? What is the difference between them?

[image]

After updating other packages, the old version of that package will remove but as you can see I have 4 versions of "Android SDK Build tools" at the same time. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

This is in case a project is tied to a specific version of the tools. You should keep them all to be able to rebuild it, for example.

Comment: This does not explain why a project that built successfully under Eclipse with SDK API18 using build tools 18.0.1 then failed to build once API19 with build tools 19.0.0 was installed. Once version 19 of the build tools was uninstalled it build OK again.

Comment: Well that's the intention but there might be bugs...